# Linux open() syscall and folder permissions

Tags: permissions, root, setuid, fork, setgid

I have a process **P** which is spawned by a process owned by root.
After **P** is created setguid() and setuid() are called and it runs as user **U**.

The process **P** attempts to create a file **f** on a folder **F** (in the root file system) which is owned by root and has the following privileges:

```
drwxrwx---    2 root     root
```

The function call look likes this:

```
open(path , O_CREAT | O_RDWR , 0660);
```

If I run the command **ps -e -o cmd,uid,euid,ruid,suid,gid,egid,rgid,sgid** 
the result is the following:

```
/my/process    500   500   500   500   500   500   500   500
```

This confirm that the process **P** is not running as root however strange enough even if the process runs as user **U** the file **f** is create under the folder **F** which should be only writable by root and its group members:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 U U
```

So the file is owned by **U**.

If I try doing the same from the bash I get a "Permission Denied" as expected:

```
$ touch /F/f
touch: cannot touch `/F/f': Permission denied
```

If I set the folder **F** permissions to:

```
drwx------    2 root     root
```

then the open() call fails with "Permission Denied" as expected.

Why can **P** create the file in that folder when writing permission has been granted to the root group?

The **ps** command shows that all uid and gid are set to the related user ids so how can it possible?

These are the group memberships of **root** and **U**:

```
$groups root
root : root

$groups U
U : U G
```

So **U** has **G** as secondary group

```
$lid -g root
 root(uid=0)
 sync(uid=5)
 shutdown(uid=6)
 halt(uid=7)
 operator(uid=11)

$lid -g U
 U(uid=500)

$lid -g G
 U(uid=500)
```

This show that only **U** is a member of **G**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @jdwolf mentions in the comments, the issue might be supplementary groups. `setgid()` doesn't remove them.

A simple test, `./drop` here is a program that calls `setregid()` and `setreuid()` to change the GID and UID to `nobody`, and then runs `id`:

```
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
# ./drop
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup),0(root)
```

There's still the zero group. Adding `setgroups(0, NULL)` (before the `setuid()`) removes that group:

```
# ./drop2
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
```

Of course, that doesn't add any of the other target user's groups.

Comment: @Bemipefe, the order of `setgid()` and `setgroups()` doesn't actually matter. You just need to leave the `setuid()` last since changing groups arbitrarily needs privileges.

Comment: Ok but since setgit() must always preceed setuid() I would place setgroups() before both function calls. I doesn't matter programmatically but it does matter from the code readability and maintenance point of view.